# Redux state management

Tags: reactjs, redux, database-normalization

I am making my first app using React and Redux. My state will need to store some lists that will have an author and a title and on each list, I will be storing 10 items(URL, description etc). I am struggling to find a good way to keep my state organized so that is easy to manage and scale. After some research, I decided to use objects with ID's instead of an array. My actions look like this:

```
const addList = (
  {
    id,
    listAuthor = '',
    listTitle = '',
  } = {}
) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_LIST',
    id: uuid(),
    list: {
      listAuthor,
      listTitle,
    }
  }
};

const addTrack = (
  {
    id,
    url = '',
    trackInfo = '',
    description = '',
  } = {}
) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TRACK',
  track: {
    id: uuid(),
    url,
    trackInfo,
    description
  }
});
```

My ADD_LIST reducer looks like this

```
export default (state = listReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_LIST':
      return {
        listIdArray: [...state.listIdArray, action.id],
        listById: {
          ...state.listById,
          [action.id]: action.list,
        }
      };
```

What would be the best way to write my ADD_TRACK reducer so that each track has the Id of the list? And is this approach right or should I be adding the tracks using the ADD_LIST action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add listId field to addTrack action, and path it as other props.

```
const addTrack = ({id,url = '',trackInfo = '', listId='',description = '',} = {}) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TRACK',
  track: {
    id: uuid(),
    listId,
    url,
    trackInfo,
    description
  }
});


addTrackReducer (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TRACK':
      return action.track
  };
```

PS About your second question: Yes, this is right. You better use declarative actions as in Redux guides said. AddTrack must have own action named ADD_TRACK or any convenient for you way.

Comment: Shouldn't I try to handle the listId from the reducer?

Comment: I was trying to do something like this: `case 'ADD_TRACK':
      return {
        ...state,
        tracksById: {
          ...state.tracksById,
          [state.listIdArray[index]]: action.track
        }
      } `, but this seems to be mutating my state, any Idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show me example json data structure of your app?

Comment: I fixed my ADD_TRACK reducer, the problem was in the action.id, I am now declaring it and assigning it a value before my return on the action.  What would be the best way to pass the id from the addList reducer as a listId to the addTrack reducer?